# Authorative DNS behind NAT possible?

Tags: bind, nat

I am currently running an authorative Bind9 DNS server for a bunch of domains. This authorative server currently replicates to a couple of slaves which are then used to meet the subnet requirement for DNS. The server is currently installed on a bare metal machine with a static WAN IP for itself.

I'd like to move this this server behind a NAT into a virtual machine. Since I don't know all that much about DNS I was wandering: are there any special constraints I need to be aware of when running an authorative DNS behind a NAT? Can I share an IP and route just bind specific ports or do I need to reserve and route a full IP for the DNS services?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope.  I don't see why you couldn't just do it by forwarding port 53 for TCP and UDP and then run the DNS server from the forwarding IP address...

Incoming Ports:

```
TCP 53
UDP 53
```

Outgoing Ports:

```
TCP 53
UDP 53
TCP/1024-65535
UDP/1024-65535
```

Comment: If the NAT is stateful, then running out of memory is a risk. Other than that, it should work.